# How can I conserve data when I change screen in React-Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

In my code, I have a page that shows a list of elements retrieved from a database. However, I also added a page that allows the user to select several filters.

I have two problems:

1. I must save the data after I get away from the page (it musts stay there)
2. I must transfer the data back to the list of elements.

I thought that by giving the filter screen a var from the previous screen, it would save the data in there, but it doesn't seem to work.

Do you have any indication about what I should do ?

```
import React from 'react'
import { SafeAreaView, View, Text } from 'react-native'
import {generalStyles} from '@gym-app/styles/general'
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next'
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

export default function ExerciseSelectorScreen({navigation}) {

    const {t} = useTranslation();
    var filterProps = {};

    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={generalStyles.contentContainer}>
            <View style={[generalStyles.contentContainer]}>
                <Text>{JSON.stringify(filterProps)}</Text>
                <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between', alignItems: 'center'}}>
                    <Text style={generalStyles.title}>{ t('exercise.exercises') }</Text>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {navigation.navigate('Exercises Filter', {filterProps: filterProps})}} style={{padding: 10, backgroundColor: '#ffb623'}}>
                        <Text style={{fontSize: 20, fontWeight: 'bold'}}>{t('general.filters').toUpperCase()}</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </View>        
        </SafeAreaView>
    )
}
```

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { View, SafeAreaView, Text, ScrollView, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import {generalStyles} from '@gym-app/styles/general'
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next'
import persistent from '@gym-app/database/persistent'
import tdb from '@gym-app/translation/object'
import CheckboxGroup from '../../components/workout/exercises/filters/CheckboxGroup'
import { useRoute } from '@react-navigation/native';

export default function ExercisesFilterScreen() {

    const {t} = useTranslation();
    const route = useRoute();
    var filterProps = route.params.filterProps;
    const [equipments, setEquipments] = useState({});
    const [selectedEquipments, setSelectedEquipments] = useState({});
    const [order, setOrder] = useState('');
    const [machine, setMachine] = useState('yes');

    useEffect(()=> {
        if (Object.values(equipments).length == 0) {
            persistent.transaction(tx => {
            tx.executeSql(
                "SELECT * FROM equipment",
                [],
                    (t, s) => {
                        var transEquip = {};
                        Object.values(s.rows._array).map((equipment) => {
                            transEquip[equipment.id] = tdb(equipment, 'name')
                        })
                        setEquipments(transEquip);
                    },
                    (t, e) => {
                        console.log(e);
                    }
                );
            });
        }
    },[equipments])

    useEffect(() => {
        filterProps.selectedEquipments = selectedEquipments;
        filterProps.order = order;
        filterProps.machine = machine;
    })

    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
            <ScrollView style={[generalStyles.contentContainer, {flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#ffb623'}]}>
                <Text style={{fontSize: 30, fontWeight: 'bold', color: '#ffffff', textAlign: 'center'}}>{t('general.filters').toUpperCase()}</Text>
                <View style={{marginTop: 10}}>
                <CheckboxGroup
                    title={t('exercise.availableEquipment')}
                    selected={selectedEquipments}
                    select={setSelectedEquipments}
                    multi={true}
                    options={
                        equipments
                    }
                />
                <CheckboxGroup
                    title={t('exercise.order')}
                    selected={order}
                    select={setOrder}
                    multi={false}
                    options={
                        {
                            "asc": t('exercise.easyToHard'),
                            "desc": t('exercise.hardToEasy'),
                        }
                    }
                    undefined={'allow'}
                />
                <CheckboxGroup
                    title={t('exercise.machines')}
                    selected={machine}
                    select={setMachine}
                    multi={false}
                    options={
                        {
                            "yes": t('exercise.machine.yes'),
                            "no": t('exercise.machine.no'),
                            "only": t('exercise.machine.only')
                        }
                    }
                />
                </View>
            </ScrollView>
        </SafeAreaView>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    optionTitle: {
        marginBottom: 6, 
        fontSize: 24, 
        fontWeight: 'bold', 
        color: '#ffffff', 
        textAlign: 'left'
    }
})
```

Comment: You can use redux. And if you want to store data even after exiting the app, you can use redux persist.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to use "global variable". By using this, you can access your data on multiple screen and re-render in your flat-list. (Redux is also the solution but initial is difficult to understand). you can initial you global variable in constructor and can update any where in the screen. here is link you can make understanding of global variable in react-native.
https://aboutreact.com/react-native-global-scope-variables/

Answer (score 0):

Either you can use redux to store the state irrespective of if you navigate to naother screen or not. It will store the state globally and whenever you need you can use its mapStateToProps method to retrieve the state value. Check this doc  : [react-redux](https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/quick-start) . You can also save the store data even when the app closes by using redux-persist, I personally prefer this as it lessens the hassle of using Asyncstorage.

Even you can use just Asyncstorage to save data.

Hope it helps .feel free for doubts